# Loading file from network driver using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, cross-validation

I am trying to save a ML model to a network drive on `spark standalone mode`. But the spark is trying to find the path on a local machine.

The path I gave was `"///server//pathtodirectory"` but spark checking the path in the local machine like `"file://server//pathtodirectory"`.

Comment: i have found that spark can only able to support read write on local file system and there's no support to readwrite on network drives